# How to get click of button to go to function in js code

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sale page, which runs sale.js whenever any input value is changed. sale.js does certain important calculations on a sale, inclduing total (final) amount, change, etc.
This form also has a button that is used to add a gift certificate. When the gift certificate is added, the button it changes from a + sign to a - sign, so that
it is then used to remove the gift certificate.

The following is a typical input field which, when changed, causes the code to run sale.js:

```
<td class="text-right cash-received-one" id="cash-received-two">Amount Tendered</td>
    <td class="text-center cash-received-one">
        <div class="floating input-group" >                                  
            <input onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" type="text" class="js-task-badge5 form-control form-control-lg is_numeric"
                id="cash-received" name="cash-received">
        </div>
     </td>
</td>
```

The following is the definition of sale.js:

```
<!-- Page JS Code -->
<?php $cb->get_js('_es6/pages/sale.js'); ?>
```

In sale.js, the function that does the calculations is badgesUpdate().  This is only run when any of the fields (like above) are changed. 
this is from a js file:

```
tasks.on('change', '.js-task-badge5', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
        this.badgesUpdate();
});
```

The following is the definition of the gift certificate field and the button:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" style="float:left%" id="gift-certificate-code" name="gift-certificate-code" >
<span style="cursor: pointer;" class="input-group-append" onclick="redeemGift();">
    <span class="input-group-text js-task-badge10">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </span>
</span>
```

In the redeemGift() function, the button is changed to a negative so that the gift certificate can be removed and other actions are taken.
I want to make sure that whenever the button is pressed, the code goes to sale.js and runs badgesUpdate().
I could take the code from BadgesUpdate() and put it into redeemGift() but that would be duplication of code and is best avoided.

Also note that when the gift certificate add or delete button is pressed, the following field is changed:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg js-task-badge4 is_numeric" id="amount-to-redeem" 
onChange="getDiscount_redeem(this.value)" style="float:left; width:70%" onKeyUp="">
```

Changes to this field (made directly on the field) do lead to entry into sale.js and badgesUpdate(), but not if they're indirect changes.  Could this field somehow be leveraged to achieve the goal?

Comment: Can you specify more what are you trying to archive ? Also please share your JS code as well to see the function. Which button click you want and where you want that to go ?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should include a complete js script, but I did share the relevant components in my request, as follows:

tasks.on('change', '.js-task-badge5', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
        this.badgesUpdate();
});

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/saleentry

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/sale

Comment: I've added links to the two files.  Hopefully that will help a bit more.  Basically when I change a variety of input fields, sale.js is run and then it detects a change in the field and goes to badgesUpdate function.  But I need this to also happen when I click the + or - button (the one that adds or removes a gift certificate).

Comment: Are you able to an online sandbox for you website. Thanks for the files but i am not able to check everything as alot of other files are missing and required to debug it properly

Comment: Yes, I have a test/demo system that I use.  I'd normally only give developers I pay access to this though.  Would you want a login, and access to all the code to help?

Comment: happy to chat privately on skype - gavinabrown.  Cheers.

Comment: Yes please. if you can share a temporary login. i will be able to check sometime today.

Comment: what's your skype id?  I'd rather share that privately.

Comment: plus I'd have to show you a few clues as to how to get to the correct screen and see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

Instead of having two click handlers, have only one function with if else statement. Let the state of the BUTTON element determine which branch of the if-else statement gets executed:

function toggleError(button) { if ( button.className === 'visible' ) { // HIDE ERROR button.className = ''; } else { // SHOW ERROR button.className = 'visible'; } }

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not sure if that relates to my specific requirement here and I didn't write that and don't want to muck around with this area of the code, which 
does work well.